# What is the "spatial structure" exactly in convolutional neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I understand what spatial information mean but I can't fully understand the spatial structure mean.
I guess it mean we make feature extraction using structure that have a spatial information in it like a kernel

I ask gpt4 and search Google but nothing about spatial structure in context of CNN